# Proper way to set up MVC Web app in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution in VS with one MVC web project. I want to add another project to represent another portion of the site. The plan is that I will work on one project, and my coworker will be working on the other one. Both are part of the same site, so the template needs to be shared between both projects.

I'm not sure if there is a best practice for setting up this type of scenario.

The idea I have is like this:

- Solution

  ..Common Project (header, footer, etc)
  ..My Project
  ..Coworker's Project

I can't figure out how to make our two projects reference the files in the common project, and it makes me think I'm probably approaching this the wrong way.

Can someone guide me here?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx Problem is if its things like a javascript file then the entire solution has to be re-compiled not just a browser refresh.

Comment: I think I may have found the answer here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307467

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible using the solution I found here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307467  I've realized that what I need to do is not think it terms of a separate project for each of us.

When I started working on this, I named my project specifically for the section I am working on. What I need to do is rename the solution and project to be more general - in this case it will be an admin site.

Then my coworker can add his stuff in the same project, using folders to organize things, and we will not bump into each other at all since we won't be working on the same code at the same time.